# prettier js formatter in command line

Tags: javascript, prettier

I would like to run [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) in the terminal command line on my linux machine, but I'm getting an error for some reason. Please advise. Here is my command:

> yarn prettier --write test.js

Here is the error I'm getting

> error Command failed with exit code 1.

Here is my file

```
foo({ num: 3 },
1, 2)
```

Answer (score -2):

yarn is just the package manager. Once installed you should be able to just use `prettier --write test.js`

Comment: I know it's an old question but I had the same problem and found this page. Not using yarn at the beginning is when you install Prettier globally. He's not wrong using yarn at the beginning.